# Issues with the camera following the spline

Tags: opengl, c++

I am trying to make a roller coaster and currently I have created a spline class which loads a spline from a text file . 
So I have all the points and I have a Catmull-Rom Spline function but I have trouble figuring how a proper track can be created from those points.

Anyone done anything similar?

edit: 
Ok i think i will make it more clear now. I was working on it yesterday that's why i didn't reply sooner.

First problem is that my camera is going off tracks. 
This is the path generated: http://prntscr.com/ci9sud drawing it as GL_LINE_STRIP.

I have a cameraUpdate function:

```
float t = (float)TrackPointIndex / (float)1000; ++TrackPointIndex;
point viewPoint = tr->over->getInterpolatedSplinePoint(t);

t = (float)TrackPointIndex / (float)1000; ++TrackPointIndex;
point nextPoint = tr->over->getInterpolatedSplinePoint(t);

std::cout << "viewPoint " << glm::to_string(viewPoint) << std::endl;
std::cout << "nextPoint " <<glm::to_string(nextPoint) << std::endl;

if (TrackPointIndex == 1000)
    TrackPointIndex = 0;


control->bodyTranslation = viewPoint;
control->bodyRotation = nextPoint;
```

which with the use of getInterpolatedSplinePoint(t) returns the viewPoint and the nextPoint which are points on the spline.  Printing them proves they are indeed on the line. But since i am using GLM i update my camera with the glm::lookAt function . So i thought that the first argument which is the camera position should be the viewPoint and the second one which is where the camera should be pointing at should be nextPoint . But that just doesn't work . 
cameraUpdate is called every 250ms or so but it is off tracks . Do i have to do any extra calculations to define where the camera should be / or be looking at?

That's my first problem.

The second one is not really a problem because i have not started working on it yet. I want to know how can somebody generate from the path a fairly good looking rail track.

Thanks.

**Edit2**: I put a sphere to travel through the tracks and it seems to be working fine . Still if i try moving the camera along the path it does not .

Anyone knows any way around this?

Comment: Where are you running into trouble? Evaluating the spline function to sample points on the curve? Deciding which points / how densely to sample?  Offsetting the curve to make two parallel rails? Extruding polygons along the sampled points to create a 2D or 3D rail with a particular cross section? The more you can tell us about what you've done and where you're stuck, the better we can target advice to help you out.

Comment: The code you've shown looks to me like it should follow the track. (Though for robustness you might want to mod by 1000 or check >= instead of ==, in case you overshoot the end). Can you show us your camera positioning & rotation code - maybe the problem is there.

Comment: Hey, for the camera i am using the glm::lookAt(this->bodyTranslation, this->bodyRotation, glm::vec3(0, 1, 0)); . So the camera is positioned in bodyTranslation and is looking towards the next point. Isn't that correct?

Comment: It sounds like you should include a video of the problem. Nothing obvious jumps out from the code alone.

Comment: Ok i will provide one soon enough. It is uploading.

Comment: Ok here we go . First video is camera standing still and just following the sphere go through the track whis is fine. Second one is the camera travelling along the spline which is not fine. first : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yv30-_AmgA4 , second: https://youtu.be/Yctqhnps8n8